# When Tap on UIcollectionviewcell zoom in cell photo and open new view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have one `UICollectionView` in a view controller, I need, when i tap on the `UICollectionViewCell`, zoom in the cell photo then open new view controller to show book content.

You can see an image below, it's a bookshelf when you tap on books then a book photo must be zoomed in and then to open content of book in new view controller.

[image]

Comment: Do you wont demo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for Zoom Cell and Transfer view..  EventlistCollection is my Collectionview..

```
  var extraview : UIView = UIView()



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        self.animateZoomforCell(DemoCollectionview.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!)
        extraview = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
        extraview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
         extraview.addSubview(DemoCollectionview.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!)
        self.view.addSubview(extraview)
}



func animateZoomforCell(zoomCell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
            let x = zoomCell.frame.size.width / 2
            let y = zoomCell.frame.size.height / 1.5
            zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x, y)
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in

               self.animateZoomforCellremove(zoomCell)
 })
    }
 func animateZoomforCellremove(zoomCell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
            zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in

               self.extraview.removeFromSuperview()
               self.DemoCollectionview.reloadData()

        })
    }
```

This code help you then please give me vote. thank you.

Comment: But I need full screen zoom in, then open view controller

Comment: @ZanaMustafa in this collection didselectItemAtIndexPath your cell zoom and after zooming cell your controller can move the next details view controller . so what you need more ?

Comment: Zooming cell is only on the uicollection area not full screen, or can you please create simple project ?

Comment: @ZanaMustafa  http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-zooming-icons-preview/  Check this demo .

Comment: Good Demo, Can you Please tell how to center the animated photo, becuase when animation start the photo went to the top of super view, that i want to be centered with screen

Comment: @ZanaMustafa then you need to calculate the point for your cell and windows and then give it scale. and your task will done ..

Comment: So far not solved, all thing is working only the photo not come to the center

Comment: @ZanaMustafa but you can do this zoom scale to calculate position of your cell to center point of view and then perform zoom